# How to split a python string based on indices?

Tags: python

I need to iterate through a list and for each element in that list, create two sublists: a sublist of the 2 elements before my current element, and a sublist of the 2 elements after.

```
for word in line.split():
\\ create sublist of the two words before word
\\ create sublist of the two words after word
```

I am not sure how to do this and would appreciate help. I know that you can generally do list[:5] but I'm not sure how to pick elements in relation to your current index.

Comment: could you give an example? what happens if word is the first item in the list?

Comment: If my line is "I would like a hamburger" I need to iterate through that line and for each word, create a sublist of the 2 words before and after my current word. So when my current word is "like," I need to output a list that is like [I, would] and then a list like [a, hamburger]

Comment: If it's the first item in the list or the last I just need to include the words after or before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think something like this is what you are looking for

```
line = "I would like a hamburger"
lst = line.split()
for index, word in enumerate(lst):
    print(lst[index-2:index],lst[index+1:index+3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` to iterate over both the index and the element, then use slicing.

```
words = line.split()
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    print("word:", word)
    print("before:", words[i-2:i])
    print("after:", words[i+1:i+3])
```

Output:

```
word: I
before: []
after: ['would', 'like']
word: would
before: ['I']
after: ['like', 'a']
word: like
before: ['I', 'would']
after: ['a', 'hamburger']
word: a
before: ['would', 'like']
after: ['hamburger']
word: hamburger
before: ['like', 'a']
after: []
```

Answer (score -1):

To look through each item in a list, simply do:

```
list = ['red', 'blue']
for item in range(len(list)):
    print(list[item])
```

Comment: That's not what OP is asking for